# How to prevent past date selection in DatePicker JDeveloper?

Tags: java, oracle, oracle-adf, jdeveloper

Im wondering is there is a way to prevent a user from selecting a past date from a date picked in JDeveloper. I have looked online but haven't found anything that seems useful.

Does anyone have any suggestions? Sorry if its a stupid question, Im quite new to JDeveloper.

Answer (score 2):

As Timo Hahn said, use minValue attribute and managed bean to get today's date.
Something like that should do:

`<af:inputdate minValue="#{myRequestScopeBean.today}" ... />`

```java
public class MyRequestScopeBean {
  public java.util.Date getToday() { return new java.util.Date(); }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

User, tell us your exact JDev version, please!

The af:choosedate and af:inputdate both have a property minValue (see https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E29542_01/apirefs.1111/e12419/tagdoc/af_inputDate.html) Set this to the current date and you got your use case.

Comment: Im using 12.2.1.3.0